# What does "is credited" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What does "is credited" mean in this sentence?

> Dr. Yunus **is credited** for pioneering the concept of microfinance.

Does it mean...?

> Dr. Yunus is believed for...

or

> Dr. Yunus have achieved something or is the reason of something for...?

Or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally "credited with", and it means "believed"

It means "people say that Dr Yunus pioneered the microfinance concept".

You might say this either because you know it is a partial truth:

> Alexander Fleming is credited with the discovery of Penicillin.

(In fact many other scientists were involved)

Or because you are not sure if something is true:

> Homer is credited with the composition of the Illiad.

(In fact we aren't sure if Homer even existed)

It is similar with saying "is alleged";

> President Trump is alleged to have colluded with the Russians.

But we would use "alleged" with something negative and "credited" with something positive.

Comment: These all seem rather negative interpretations. I am certain that the phrase can also be used as a way of saying "the world knows X did ..."

Comment: @JamesK According to the context, are we allowed to to change the sentence and say: **Dr. Yunus is credited as being the father of microfinance**. Does it make sense?

Comment: You may,  but I still prefer "with".

Answer (score 0):

When discussing recognition, we can use the phrasal verb 'credit with' to say that someone is credited **with** an achievement, invention, etc.

> *to consider that someone has a particular quality:*
>
> I had credited them with more integrity than they showed. ​
>
> *to say that someone is responsible for something good:*
>
> She is credited with making the business a success.

[Credit somebody with something (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credit-sb-with-sth?q=credit-sb-with-sth_1)